# build a DataFrame with columns from tuple of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am struggling with the basic task of constructing a DataFrame of counts by value from a tuple produced by `np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)`, such as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)  
birds=np.random.choice(['African Swallow','Dead Parrot','Exploding Penguin'], size=int(5e4))
someTuple=np.unique(birds, return_counts = True)
someTuple
#(array(['African Swallow', 'Dead Parrot', 'Exploding Penguin'], 
#       dtype='<U17'), array([16510, 16570, 16920], dtype=int64))
```

First I tried

```
pd.DataFrame(list(someTuple))
# Returns this:
#                  0            1                  2
# 0  African Swallow  Dead Parrot  Exploding Penguin
# 1            16510        16570              16920
```

I also tried `pd.DataFrame.from_records(someTuple)`, which returns the same thing.

But what I'm looking for is this:

```
#              birdType      birdCount
# 0     African Swallow          16510  
# 1         Dead Parrot          16570  
# 2   Exploding Penguin          16920
```

What's the right syntax?

Comment: your second method would have been close with additional '.T' functionality:
pd.DataFrame.from_records(someTuple).T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one NumPy based solution with [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) -

```
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(someTuple),columns=['birdType','birdCount'])
```

Or with [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) -

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(someTuple).T,columns=['birdType','birdCount'])
```

Benchmarking `np.transpose`, `np.column_stack` and `np.vstack` for staking   `1D` arrays into columns to form a `2D` array -

```
In [54]: tup1 = (np.random.rand(1000),np.random.rand(1000))

In [55]: %timeit np.transpose(tup1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.9 µs per loop

In [56]: %timeit np.column_stack(tup1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11 µs per loop

In [57]: %timeit np.vstack(tup1).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: These are both very fast numpy solutions, just what I was looking for.  An equally fast answer was `pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(someTuple), columns=['birdType', 'birdCount'])` which another user gave but then deleted (not sure why).

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Added some timings on those three, all look equally fast it seems.

Answer (score 5):

Using your tuple, you can do the following:

```
In [4]: pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*someTuple)), columns = ['Bird', 'BirdCount'])
Out[4]: 
                Bird  BirdCount
0    African Swallow      16510
1        Dead Parrot      16570
2  Exploding Penguin      16920
```

Answer (score 5):

create a dictionary

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(birdType=someTuple[0], birdCount=someTuple[1]))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I need to start using the plain dictionary constructor with keyword arguments more often. It really is very convenient.

Comment: Pining for the fjords!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Counter.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(birds)

>>> pd.Series(c)
African Swallow      16510
Dead Parrot          16570
Exploding Penguin    16920
dtype: int64
```

You could also use `value_counts` on the series.

```
>>> pd.Series(birds).value_counts()
Exploding Penguin    16920
Dead Parrot          16570
African Swallow      16510
dtype: int64
```